# Are prompt and PROMPT tied in zsh?

Tags: zsh

```
$ echo ${(t)prompt}
scalar-special
$ echo ${(t)PROMPT}
scalar-special
```

Zsh shows that they are special, but does not show that they are tied like:

```
$ echo ${(t)manpath}
array-tied-special
$ echo ${(t)MANPATH}
scalar-tied-export-special
```

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "tied". `prompt` and `PROMPT` both share the same underlying value, but they are not tied in the sense defined by the `-T` option to `typeset` (as exemplified by `path` and `PATH`).

Comment: @chepner Thanks. How can we create variable pairs like `prompt` and `PROMPT`?

Comment: I don't know that you can.

Answer (score 1):

From the man page:

```
   PROMPT <S> <Z>
          Same as PS1 ...
   prompt <S> <Z>
          Same as PS1.
```

This means that if you modify one of `PROMPT`, `prompt` or `PS1`, and then look at one of the other two variables, you will see that your modifications are there as well.

```
PROMPT=foo
echo $PS1 # outputs foo
echo $prompt # outputs foo
```